# Regex: How to capture second and third double quotes values

Tags: regex

I want to get the values of oauth_token and oauth_token_secret in the following string using two regular expressions.

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_signature="QkLCQkI%3D", oauth_token="7410ac05e77e117d24ef98904344a3e6", oauth_token_secret="811ebaa48f432ffc070d5b7f4c8e6906"
```

Using following expression I can get all double quotes values, but I can't find how to extract only oauth_token_secret or oauth_token.

```
"([^"]*)"
```

Comment: `oauth_token="([^"]*)"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a simple solution would be:

```
oauth_token(?:_secret)?="([^"]*)"
```

This will only match the quoted strings preceded by `oauth_token=` or `oauth_token_secret=`. The first capture group would contain the value within the quotes. This is especially useful if the order of the values could vary.

Alternatively, if your chosen regex engine supports look-behinds, you could use:

```
(?<=oauth_token(?:_secret)?=)"([^"]*)"
```

This works just like the previous pattern, except the name preceding the value will not be captured. The quotes around the value will still be captured. If you want these to be excluded as well, you'll need a look-ahead, too:

```
(?<=oauth_token(?:_secret)?=")[^"]*(?=")
```

And finally, note that this could match a value like `foo_oauth_token="bar"`. In case you need to exclude any sequence where there are some other word characters immediately preceding the `oauth_token` / `oauth_token_secret`, place a `\b` in front of the `oath`:

```
\boauth_token(?:_secret)?="([^"]*)"

(?<=\boauth_token(?:_secret)?=")[^"]*(?=")
```

Comment: I want only the value 7410ac05e77e117d24ef98904344a3e6 or 811ebaa48f432ffc070d5b7f4c8e6906. It should not contain oauth_token= or oauth_token_secret=

How can I do this?

Comment: @user3411647 You just have to extract the first capture group. Precisely how you do this depends on what language / platform you're using. However, I've provided another solution that may help. See my updated answer.